# How to accumulate and sum values from two arrays?

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have 2 arrays (array 2 is multidimensional) that look like this:

```
Array 1 = 
 [1795, 3449, 41, 1261, 99, 38162, 36, 7, 2768, 53, 1800]

Array 2 = 
 [[33, 0, 0, 433, 17, 2388, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [508, 0, 0, 242, 36, 800,  0, 0, 5, 0, 0],
 [285, 0, 0, 0,   0,  1600, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0,   0, 0, 0,   0,  1700, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0,   0, 0, 0,   0,  0,    0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

The arrays will always be the same length.

What I am trying to do is accumulate the values in each array position, so they should look like this:

```
[[1795, 3449, 41, 1261, 99,  38162, 36, 7, 2768]
[1828, 3449, 41, 1694, 116, 40550, 36, 7, 2768]
[2336, 3449, 41, 1936, 152, 41350, 36, 7, 2773]
[2621, 3449, 41, 1936, 152, 42950, 36, 7, 2773]
[2621, 3449, 41, 1936, 152, 44650, 36, 7, 2773]
[2621, 3449, 41, 1936, 152, 44650, 36, 7, 2773]]
```

The final array will take the value from the row above and accumulate the value downwards.

I've tried using map and reduce but I think because array 2 is multidimensional and that I'm still a novice with JS, I can't get it work. Any help would be appreciated.

This is what I have already tried:

```
var yearSums = array1.map(function (array1Map) {
    return [parseInt(array1Map) + parseInt(array2)]
})
```

That gives me this:

```
[1828.0, 3482.0, 74.0, 1294.0, 132.0, 38195.0, 69.0, 40.0, 2801.0, 86.0, 1833.0]
```

What it does is add the first element in array 2 (33) to every value in array 1.

Comment: What have you actually tried to  achieve this? Add your code.

Comment: So... is the first row replaced by array1?

Comment: @Ruben Apps-script tag would mean ES3 syntax.

Comment: AFAIK tags should be derived from question / relevant answers content. None of them of this thread mention that a specific JavaScript version or related platform. What make you consider that [tag:google-apps-script] should be included on this question ? Have you notice that ther is already an answer using arrow functions posted before my edit? By the way we have [tag:ecmascript-3].

Comment: @Ruben Thank you for your reply.  Although not explicitly mentioned in the question itself, I believe OP included the tag to let us know that this is Google-apps-script. [Tour] page does say `All questions are tagged with their subject areas`. If OP considers it as a subject area, and the tag is not unrelated to the question at hand, I don't think it should be removed based on answer''s content.

Comment: @TheMaster IMHO "subject areas" should be derived from the content. At this time the accepted answer and the question doesn't include anything about [tag:google-apps-script] and [tag:google-sheets]

Comment: @Ruben I respect your opinion. But, Do you agree that the question still might be about "arrays usage" in [tag:google-apps-script]? Or If  javascript was not tagged originally, Do you think it's still a valid question with only google-apps-script tag? I think tags are part of question content. People shouldn't need to explicitly state the tags again in the question: "I am using python for so and so" in the body of the question. I might be wrong in the whole matter, seeing as I'm  relatively a new member, But these are my thoughts.

Comment: @TheMaster I respect your opinion too. I a agree with you that you might be wrong ;) as well I or even both of us might wrong. Just think on this, the content (question and relevant answers body) rule, the question title and tags should follow it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can also use Array.reduce to achieve the same result.

```js
var arr1 = [1795, 3449, 41, 1261, 99, 38162, 36, 7, 2768, 53, 1800];
var arr2 = [
  [33, 0, 0, 433, 17, 2388, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [508, 0, 0, 242, 36, 800, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0],
  [285, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1600, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1700, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
];
var sumArr = arr2.reduce(
  function(acc, curr) {
    acc.push(
      acc[acc.length - 1].map(function(col, idx) {
        return col + curr[idx];
      })
    );
    return acc;
  },
  [arr1] //Initialize Array1 as a 2D array.
);
console.log(sumArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Only works with arrays of same length.

You have to loop inside each array for each array index get the value and sum them up.

**UPDATE**

Didn't get what you was expecting first time. updated script

```js
var array1 = 
 [1795, 3449, 41, 1261, 99, 38162, 36, 7, 2768, 53, 1800]

var array2 = 
 [[33, 0, 0, 433, 17, 2388, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [508, 0, 0, 242, 36, 800,  0, 0, 5, 0, 0],
 [285, 0, 0, 0,   0,  1600, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0,   0, 0, 0,   0,  1700, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0,   0, 0, 0,   0,  0,    0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

var summedArray = array2.map(arr => arr.map((subArr,i) => subArr +array1[i])) 

console.log(summedArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the first array (let's call it `acc`) as an accumulator while mapping the nested array (`table`) in a nested fashion:

```
 const result = table.map(row => row.map((value, index) => acc[index] += value));
```

This will mutate the first array though, clone it if you need immutability.

Comment: The question's tags include [tag:google-apps-script]. Assuming that the purpose of the OP was to add context to the question, then your proposed solution can't be used as Google Apps Script doesn't support arrow functions.